# JQuery, Hide and Toggle DIV , FAQs page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an XSL page reading from XML, it show a question and answer as below :

```
<div class="faqs">
    <xsl:for-each select ="TSPRoot/FAQS/FAQ">
<div class="flip">
    <xsl:value-of select ="Question"/>
</div>
<div class="panel">
    <xsl:value-of  select ="Answer" disable-output-escaping ="yes"/>
</div>
    </xsl:for-each >
</div>
```

and I have this Jquery :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".flip").click(function(){
          $(".panel").hide("fast");
          $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
      });
  });
</script>
```

The requested is that when i click on any question the other answers well hide and only the answer of the clicked question will appear , and this is going just fine ... My problem is that the question stay clickable and when you click it will call the function again and it hides and show repeatedly

I need to make it un-clickable unless you clicked another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the toggle from this

```
$(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
```

to

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

      $(".flip").click(function(){
          $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
          $(this).next().slideDown(5000).addClass('selected');
          $(".panel").not('.selected').hide("fast");         
       });
   });
```

Comment: Scott Selby ,, Thanks alot , but i want it to be un-clickable once i clicked it ,, I don't want to be able to click the same question two times in a row unless i clicked other question

Comment: @user1939819 , this will appear unclickable , the slideDown will not perform any animation if it is already down

Comment: @user1939819 - if you really want it unclickable , (the user will never notice a difference ) , but if you must make it unclickable then you are going to need unique id's on each .flip and global variable remembering what was clicked.

Comment: But the div (.panel) will hide each time you click the (.flip) div, even when i added the (5000)